# Getting error after running powershell script to query data from mysql to csv

Tags: mysql, powershell

The following code below is what I wrote to query from multiple tables and filter by dat.

```
###PROMPT USER FOR DETAILS
Param(
[Parameter(
Mandatory = $true,
ParameterSetName = '',
ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
[string]$Query
)

$MySQLAdminUserName = xxxx
$MySQLAdminPassword = xxxx
$MySQLDatabase = xxxxx
$MySQLHost = 'localhost'
#$ConnectionString = "server=" + $MySQLHost + ";port=3306;uid=" + $MySQLAdminUserName + ";pwd="       
+ $MySQLAdminPassword + ";database="+$MySQLDatabase
$ConnectionString =   
"Server=$MySQLHost;Uid=$MySQLAdminUserName;Pwd=$MySQLAdminPassword;database=$MySQLDatabase;Allow   
User Variables=True;"
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data") 
$mysql = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection($ConnectionString)
$mysql.Open()
$sqlquery1 = "SELECT
DISTINCT upper(personnel_employee.emp_code) as Employee_ID,
upper(personnel_employee.first_name)as First_Name,
upper(personnel_employee.last_name) as Last_Name,
date_format(att_payloadbase.att_date,'%Y/%m/%d') as Att_Date ,
dayname(att_payloadbase.att_date) as Week_Day,
if(weekday(att_payloadbase.att_date)IN(5,6) ,'Weekend','') as Exception,
IF(att_holiday.alias = '', IFNULL(att_holiday.alias,0), IFNULL(att_holiday.alias,0))as Holiday,
att_timeinterval.alias as TimeTable,
round((att_payloadbase.duration)/60,2) as Duration,
date_format(att_payloadbase.check_in,'%Y/%m/%d %T') as Check_In,
date_format(att_payloadbase.check_out,'%Y/%m/%d %T')as Check_Out,
round((att_payloadbase.duty_duration)/60,2) as Duty_Duration,
att_payloadbase.work_day,
date_format(att_payloadbase.clock_in,'%Y/%m/%d %T') as Clock_In,
date_format(att_payloadbase.clock_out,'%Y/%m/%d %T') as Clock_Out,
round((att_payloadbase.total_time)/60,2) as Total_Time,
round((att_payloadbase.actual_worked)/60,2) as Actual_WT,
IF(att_holiday.alias!='' ,480, 0+ round((att_payloadbase.total_worked)/60,2)) as Total_WT,
round((att_payloadovertime.normal_ot)/60,2) as Normal_OT,
round((att_payloadovertime.weekend_ot)/60,2) as Weekend_OT,
round((att_payloadovertime.holiday_ot)/60,2) as Holiday_OT,
round((att_payloadovertime.total_ot)/60,2) as Total_OT
FROM att_payloadbase inner JOIN personnel_employee ON att_payloadbase.emp_id =      
personnel_employee.id
left JOIN att_timeinterval ON att_payloadbase.timetable_id = att_timeinterval.id
left JOIN att_holiday ON att_payloadbase.att_date = att_holiday.start_date
left JOIN att_payloadovertime ON att_payloadbase.overtime_id = att_payloadovertime.uuid
WHERE date_format(att_payloadbase.att_date,'%Y%m%d') ='$Query' AND personnel_employee.status    
<100 LIMIT 10"
$req = New-Object Mysql.Data.MysqlClient.MySqlCommand($sqlquery1,$mysql)
$dataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($req)
$dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "Query1") | Out-Null
# Get the date
$DateStamp = (Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmmss");

#File Location"
$filename = "C:/DataExchange/Test/Time_Card_$DateStamp.csv"

$dataSet.Tables["Query1"] | Export-Csv -path $filename  -NoTypeInformation;
```

After running the script, I receive this error below:

```
Exception calling "Fill" with "2" argument(s): "Fatal error encountered during command   
execution."
At C:\Scripts\Attendance_Report_By_Date.ps1:57 char:1
+ $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "Query1") | Out-Null
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MySqlException

Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\Scripts\Attendance_Report_By_Date.ps1:64 char:29
+ ... et.Tables["Query1"] | Export-Csv -path $filename  -NoTypeInformation;
+                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :   
ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

I have tried formatting the date before filtering for a specific date.
Without Using the WHERE condition in the sql query, I am able to generate the csv file with records or data.

Comment: I doubt `date_format(att_payloadbase.att_date,'%Y%m%d') ='Query1'` is every doing to be true. What happens if you pass an actual date-string?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen when i put an actual date-string, i get the same error. if i remove some of the joins, i get the records. I do not know if it times-out.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It was working perfect until we changed the  server to windows server 2022 from server 2012